# Is there a connection object in javascript server pages?

Tags: javascript

I ran across this script in http://jssp.sourceforge.net/

See annotated image:

[image]

Is there a "connection" object in JSSP, JSSQL, that allows the functions run(), next() to be called from the variable "stmt" and "rset" when we assign "connection" object to those variables?

I am presuming yes, in the following statement: "// Closing the connection automatically closes all associated resources.
connection.close();"

Where can we find documentation online regarding the connection object? Searched but cannot find it.

Comment: http://jssp.sourceforge.net/jssql_description.html#_h3_Database_connections_h3_

Comment: Given you are simply asking for documentation reference(s) I cannot see this as a good fit here as a question, perhaps rework it with actual code you have tried and what issues you ran into.

Comment: This JSSP project looks obsolete and abandoned.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an offsite resource documentation set

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is "Java" not "Javascript". Different languages, Javascript was named thusly for marketing purposes :-) That said, yes there is a connection object. But, var stmt is being given a value returned from connection.SELECT ID, NAME FROM TEST;

Comment: No, this really is JavaScript Server Pages.  Click the link in the question.  I know, I had the same reaction.

Comment: Hah! Wow, the original Node.js ... blushing sheepishly